# Gstreamer and Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: libcamera, v4l2, gstreamer

For a couple of days I'm trying to make the gstreamer work on my new RPI5

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

System is fresh installed with a SD image.
I'm using IMX477 camera. In order to make it work I did changes in `/boot/firmware/config.txt`

```
camera_auto_detect=0
dtoverlay=imx477
```

Camera works well with `libcamera-hello` and `rpicam-hello`.

The installation of Gstreamer I did with help of https://qengineering.eu/install-gstreamer-1.18-on-raspberry-pi-4.html :

```
# install a missing dependency
$ sudo apt-get install libx264-dev libjpeg-dev
# install the remaining plugins
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev \
     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
     libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
     gstreamer1.0-tools \
     gstreamer1.0-gl \
     gstreamer1.0-gtk3
```

The installation is successful and after `gst-inspect-1.0 --version` I get:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.22.0
GStreamer 1.22.0
https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gstreamer1.0
```

PROBLEMS:

When I run rpicam-hello, I get a lot of warnings about unsupported V4L2 formats:

```
$ rpicam-hello
            [0:35:59.484703707] [2724]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+118-563cd78e
            [0:35:59.498479530] [2725]  INFO RPI pisp.cpp:653 libpisp version v1.0.1 5652744a74d7 10-12-2023 (15:21:50)
            [0:35:59.519595016] [2725]  INFO RPI pisp.cpp:1112 Registered camera /base/axi/pcie@120000/rp1/i2c@80000/imx477@1a to CFE device /dev/media1 and ISP device /dev/media2 using PiSP variant BCM2712_C0
            Made X/EGL preview window
            [0:35:59.906002770] [2724]  WARN V4L2 v4l2_pixelformat.cpp:338 Unsupported V4L2 pixel format Y16 
            [0:35:59.906033818] [2724]  WARN V4L2 v4l2_pixelformat.cpp:338 Unsupported V4L2 pixel format RGB6
            [0:35:59.906041317] [2724]  WARN V4L2 v4l2_pixelformat.cpp:338 Unsupported V4L2 pixel format BGR6
            [0:35:59.906049926] [2724]  WARN V4L2 v4l2_pixelformat.cpp:338 Unsupported V4L2 pixel format PC1M
            Mode selection for 2028:1520:12:P
                SRGGB10_CSI2P,1332x990/0 - Score: 3456.22
                SRGGB12_CSI2P,2028x1080/0 - Score: 1083.84
                SRGGB12_CSI2P,2028x1520/0 - Score: 0
                SRGGB12_CSI2P,4056x3040/0 - Score: 887
            Stream configuration adjusted
            [0:35:59.906341879] [2724]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 2028x1520-YUV420 (1) 2028x1520-BGGR16_PISP_COMP1
            [0:35:59.906501639] [2725]  INFO RPI pisp.cpp:1396 Sensor: /base/axi/pcie@120000/rp1/i2c@80000/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 2028x1520-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected CFE format: 2028x1520-PC1B
```

When trying to run the code: [https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#the-libcamerasrc-element][1] I get a warning and nothing happens.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 libcamerasrc ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=NV12 ! v4l2convert ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="controls,repeat_sequence_header=1" ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "libcamerasrc"
```

When using v4l2src instead I get error:

```
$ GST_DEBUG=1 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.072092495  2823 0x5555eaf8d360 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:712:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_streamon:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> error with STREAMON 22 (Invalid argument)
0:00:00.072167123  2823 0x5555eaf8d360 ERROR             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:572:gst_buffer_pool_set_active:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> start failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate required memory.
Additional debug info:
../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2src.c(976): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Buffer pool activation failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3132): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.019579174
Setting pipeline to NULL
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Not sure more what I can do.
Its possible that some libraries werent installed. Because I also miss `v4l2h264dec` and others

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 video4linux2
Plugin Details:
  Name                     video4linux2
  Description              elements for Video 4 Linux
  Filename                 /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so
  Version                  1.22.0
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-good
  Documentation            https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video4linux2/
  Source release date      2023-01-23
  Binary package           GStreamer Good Plugins (Debian)
  Origin URL               https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gst-plugins-good1.0

  v4l2deviceprovider: Video (video4linux2) Device Provider
  v4l2radio: Radio (video4linux2) Tuner
  v4l2sink: Video (video4linux2) Sink
  v4l2src: Video (video4linux2) Source

  4 features:
  +-- 3 elements
  +-- 1 device providers
```